# Strip debug information from libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, debug-symbols, grpc-c#

My team has recently started using gRPC in our product built on .Net Framework. Due to the high volume of debug symbols in mainly libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so our build artifact has exploded from 50 MB to 400 MB. This introduced some problems in our CI/CD environment and also in our delivery chain due to low Internet bandwidth.

I would like to reduce the size of our build artifact.
I know that debug symbols can be stripped from libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so using binutils/strip command.

Is that the best way? Or are there some settings in Visual Studio (csproj, sln), Nuget or MSBuild that can be applied to remove debug information from the inherited gRPC so files?

What is the easiest way to use binutils/strip on Windows?

Comment: Why would debug information increase the size of the deployed build artifacts? Do you distribute the build logs?

Comment: Sorry, I meant debug symbols in the gRPC binary. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that msbuild cannot get that. `so` file is bases on linux and **VS IDE** is based on Windows and cannot handle the so file. And it is not generated by MSBuild, VS IDE and is copied from nuget package into your output files based on the `RuntimeIdentifier`.

**But** the file is generated by other tool rather VS IDE and VS IDE and MSBuild cannot handle it and it is just copied from the third tool into your VS IDE.

**In fact**, if it is `dll` type(Windows) and you have the open source code of the  `libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64` project.

**Note**: you have to modify the open source code by MSBuild at the very beginning and then you could generate the file without dll info. And there is no other option to remove the debug info after the re-generate process.

**And** then you could add these at the bottom of the `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>

<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>none</DebugType>

</PropertyGroup>
```

**And** then rebuild the source code to generate the dll without debug info. That is MSBuild function.

**But** that is for Windows. And it is not suitable for your linux file. And there is no option about it on MSBuild, Nuget, csproj file.

**So** the best function is use your method, third party stripping tool that uses binutils/strip command. And it is more easier and suitable.